# ServiceStack's Ormlite Delete not working

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I've made up a generic repository to make CRUD operations in a MVC project.

When i try to delete a row from a table that has an identity on SQLServer, the code generated by the Ormlite `Delete` method and inspected with the profiler doesn't not affect any rows.

This is the Crud operation for the deletion (pretty simple):

```
    public void Destroy<T>(T entity)
    {
        using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
        {
            db.Delete<T>(entity);
        }
    }
```

The Type `T` in my test is represented by the following class:

```
[Alias("FT_TEST_DEVELOPMENT")]
public class TestTable
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DESCR { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATE { get; set; }
    public decimal PRICE { get; set; }
    public int? QTY { get; set; }
}
```

And the inspected code corresponds to the following:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM "FT_TEST_DEVELOPMENT" WHERE "ID"=@ID AND "DESCR"=@DESCR AND "TIMESTAMP"=@TIMESTAMP AND "DATE"=@DATE AND "PRICE"=@PRICE AND "QTY"=@QTY ',
               N'@ID int,@DESCR nvarchar(6),@TIMESTAMP datetime,@DATE datetime,@PRICE decimal(2,0),@QTY int',
               @ID=4,@DESCR=N'SECOND',@TIMESTAMP=NULL,@DATE='2015-06-01 00:00:00',@PRICE=15,@QTY=NULL
```

When I execute this perfectly sensed statement the server tells me that no row

Disclaimer: as some names where in my native language, I translated them so there may be little grammar error, if it's so, let me note and I'll edit.

**UPDATE**

The matching row actually EXISTS in the database

SELECT * FROM FT_TEST_DEVELOPMENT WHERE ID= 4
   ID   DESCR   TIMESTAMP   DATE         PRICE    QTY
   4    SECOND  NULL        2015-06-01   15       NULL

I mean that actually the OrmLite generated code appears to be bugged.

And yes, the ID column is the table's key.

**SECOND UPDATE**
I think I've found the cause:

actually in the `WHERE` clause the NULL fields are assigned in the way

```
@TIMESTAMP=NULL
```

but actually the SQL server will not match this statement, because it expects to receive

```
WHERE [...] AND "TIMESTAMP" IS NULL [...]
```

Comment: Have you defined `ID` as a primary key in the table or is it just an `IDENTITY`? `IDENTITY` doesn't mark a field as primary key

Comment: Kalispera! I've also tried with the **[PrimaryKey]** attribute, but nothing changed, anyway I'll edit the question, THX

Comment: You need to put [PrimaryKey] there *and* make sure ID is a primary key on the table. Also, I suspect `db.Delete<T>()` is a typo and you meant `db.Delete<T>(entity)`. All this should change the statement's `WHERE` clause to check only the ID field. Also make sure there *are* rows that match the criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `db.Delete()` API works [has been updated](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/2670b3c11b994df93b72d57c58681168281b1aad) so that `NULL` fields are moved out of the parameterized queries and appended to the SQL filter so this should now work from **v4.0.37+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

You can also delete rows in OrmLite by PrimaryKey with:

```
Db.DeleteById<TestTable>(entity.Id);
```

For generic methods you can use the `T.GetId()` extension method to get the value of the Id field, i.e:

```
Db.DeleteById<TestTable>(entity.GetId());
```

Or to delete using every **non** `null` property in the `DELETE` WHERE criteria, you can use:

```
Db.DeleteNonDefaults(entity);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but just one more question. Why even if the dialect is **SqlServerDialect.Provider** the generated **WHERE** clause won't match any rows?

Comment: @Pizzaboy Because it uses a parameterized query to perform the filter and comparing a null field with a parameterized value (even if it's DbNull) yields a false condition. You can use `Db.DeleteNonDefaults()` so null fields aren't used in the filter, otherwise my preference is to delete using the Primary Key with `Db.DeleteById()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the same statement in SSMS and nothing gets deleted, it's because no row matches the criteria.

OrmLite expects the primary key of an entity to be named `Id` (case-sensitive). Your property is named `ID` and the `[PrimaryKey]` attribute wasn't specified. In this case OrmLite has to use all available fields in the `WHERE` clause to find the rows to delete.

`AutoIncrement` doesn't mean the field is a key, just that its value is auto-generated by the server and comes from an identity column. The same applies with SQL Server - an identity column isn't a primary key, you need to define the primary key separately.

You need to either rename `ID` to `Id` or add the `[PrimaryKey]` attribute to it.